# Error parsing XML: mismatched tag (invalid token)

Tags: android

1.The error is on the line where I open TextView tag, but it has been moving around to different lines so I'm not sure.
2. Also, sorry if its just poorly written, this is my first attempt at programming

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ide="@+id/text_prompt"
        android:text="Enter the total bill amount"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </requestFocus>
    <EditText/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20 Percent" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="15 Percent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="10 Percent" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tip_prompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Select a tip amount:"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 errors here.

1. You've closed root RelativeLayout too early (line 5) - `should be > instead of />`
2. You've closed EditText too early (line 24) - `should be > instead of />`
3. Wrong syntax at line 26 - should be `<requestFocus /> instead of </requestFocus>`
4. Wrong syntax at line 27 - should be `</EditText> instead of <EditText/>`

Correct xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ide="@+id/text_prompt"
        android:text="Enter the total bill amount"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="20 Percent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="15 Percent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tip10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="10 Percent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tip_prompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:text="Select a tip amount:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: now its giving me a junk after document element error

Comment: still same thing. i was following a tutorial so i don't know what's wrong

Comment: well shit, now its saying this on line 27 instead. Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The element type "RelativeLayout" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</
  RelativeLayout>".
 - This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint
 - error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

Comment: i copied and pasted that but still getting a mismatched tag error. thanks a ton for your replies but i think it might be time to just start a new project

Comment: What do you use? Eclipse?

Comment: yeah, thats what some friends reccomemded

Comment: @MattBoggs, please delete it and use Anroid Studio. http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

Comment: i got that first but then went to eclipse. I'll try it out

Comment: moved it over to Android Studio, cut out some eclipse specific lines and it runs now! thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 1):

you did close the tag of the root RelativeLayout. Note `/>` in

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

it should be just `>`

Comment: did i do the same thing on the first EditText?

Comment: no. Only for subclass of ViewGroup. E.g. RelativeLayour or  LinearLayout, that can have children. EditText can't have children. So you can close its tag immediately

Answer (score 0):

You closed the relative root tag too early. 
where all you have to do is remove the "/" from the />
How its structure usually goes is 
Or you could do  but you can't do   which is what you attempted to do with your code. It'll compile after its corrected.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >.   </relativelayout>
```